# how to access a specific result of a groupby grouper method grouped with frequency on quarters

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(pd.date_range('2019-10-01', '2022-10-31'), 15),
                  columns=['Date'])
df['NUM'] = np.random.randint(1, 600, df.shape[0])
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', axis=0, freq='Q-DEC')).sum()
df_test = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', axis=0, freq='Q-DEC')).sum()
df_test.iloc[-1]
```

So I can assign the groupby to a variable making another dataframe and then access any one entry of the groupby...in this instance the last entry.  My question is can I avoid creating df_test altogether to access the last entry (or any entry I care to access)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.tail(1)` at the end of groupby statement like this:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', axis=0, freq='Q-DEC')).sum().tail(1)
```

Comment: To me, this is so interesting of an answer in that most answers I see show a new way of doing things with methods and approaches I am aware of.  Tail is something I never even thought existed.